# How to add only required url of third party app in django?

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

my url : I have included third party app django djoser . There are several urls of the third party app . But I want only specific ones.

```
urlpatterns = [
path('apis/token/', TokenObtainPairView.as_view(), name='token_obtain_pair'),
path('apis/token/refresh/', TokenRefreshView.as_view(), name='token_refresh'),
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('auth/', include('djoser.urls')),
path("auth/", include("djoser.urls.jwt")),
]
```

Here are all the urls obtained from djoser . But I want only some urls and neglect the others.

```
^auth/ ^users/$ [name='user-list']
^auth/ ^users\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$ [name='user-list']
^auth/ ^users/activation/$ [name='user-activation']
^auth/ ^users/activation\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$ [name='user-activation']
^auth/ ^users/me/$ [name='user-me']
^auth/ ^users/me\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$ [name='user-me']
^auth/ ^users/resend_activation/$ [name='user-resend-activation']
^auth/ ^users/resend_activation\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$ [name='user-resend-activation']
^auth/ ^users/reset_password/$ [name='user-reset-password']
^auth/ ^users/reset_password\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$ [name='user-reset-password']
^auth/ ^users/reset_password_confirm/$ [name='user-reset-password-confirm']
^auth/ ^users/reset_password_confirm\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$ [name='user-reset-password-confirm']
^auth/ ^users/reset_username/$ [name='user-reset-username']
^auth/ ^users/reset_username\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$ [name='user-reset-username']
^auth/ ^users/reset_username_confirm/$ [name='user-reset-username-confirm']
^auth/ ^users/reset_username_confirm\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$ [name='user-reset-username-confirm']
^auth/ ^users/set_password/$ [name='user-set-password']
^auth/ ^users/set_password\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$ [name='user-set-password']
^auth/ ^users/set_username/$ [name='user-set-username']
^auth/ ^users/set_username\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$ [name='user-set-username']
^auth/ ^users/(?P<id>[^/.]+)/$ [name='user-detail']
^auth/ ^users/(?P<id>[^/.]+)\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$ [name='user-detail']
^auth/ ^$ [name='api-root']
^auth/ ^\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$ [name='api-root']
```

Comment: Then don't include them, just redefine the ones you want.

Comment: @dirkgroten can you please be more specific??

Comment: Instead of including the djoser.urls, include your own urls file where you define them one by one. Like you would with your own urls. Just import the relevant views from djoser. E.g `path('users/', djoser.views.UserList.as_view(), name='user_list')`. I don’t know the exact name of the views so this is just a guess. Look it up in the djoser source code.

Comment: Most views are defined as actions on the `UserViewSet` so the path example above should be `path('users/', UserViewSet.as_view({'get': 'list'}), name='user_list')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only choice I come up with is;

1. Make a child viewset from djoser UserViewSet:

   ```
   # views.py
   from djoser.views import UserViewSet

   class MyViewSet(UserViewSet):
       """Put your desired views and functions here"
   ```
2. Then add your views to your urls.py

   ```
   from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter

   from .views import MyViewSet

   custom_router = DefaultRouter()
   router.register("users", MyViewSet)

   urlpatterns = [...] #your other urls

   urlpatterns += [url(r'/', include(custom_router.urls))]
   ```

Hope this helps!

Comment: should I include the serializers , querysets also??